# Issue with RegEx in bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have the following RegEx written to match any no of repeating patterns. It is working in `https://regex101.com/` when tested online. But, it is not working when used in Linux Bash. Please help!!

`pair_format="^([[:blank:]]*\[[[:blank:]]*[^=[\]]+[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[^=[\]]+[[:blank:]]*\][[:blank:]]*)+$"`

Sample data to test:

`CUSTOM_ARGS_KV="[X=Y][A=B][C=D][FASLFJSDLF=9]"`

`if [[ ! $CUSTOM_ARGS_KV =~ $pair_format ]]; then; echo "invalid!!!!"; else echo "valid"; fi`

Here is my script:

```sh
CUSTOM_ARGS_KV='[X=Y][A=B][C=D][FASLFJSDLF=9]' #example input
if [ ! -z "$CUSTOM_ARGS_KV" ]; then
    pair_format="^([[:blank:]]*\[[[:blank:]]*[^=[\]]+[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[^=[\]]+[[:blank:]]*\][[:blank:]]*)+$"
    if [[ ! $CUSTOM_ARGS_KV =~ $pair_format ]]; then
        echo "Error! CUSTOM_ARGS_KV is not according to format [key1=value1] [key2=value2] etc. Or either of key/value of a pair are kept blank"
    exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: To begin with, you are not supposed to quote the test. So it would be **if [[ ! "$CUSTOM_ARGS_KV" =~ $pair_format ]]**.

Comment: Okay. I edited the question now. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
pair_format="^(\[[^]=[]+=[^]=[]\])+$"
CUSTOM_ARGS_KV="[X=Y][A=B][C=D][FASLFJSDLF=9]"

[[ $CUSTOM_ARGS_KV =~ $pair_format ]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid"
```

```
valid
```

It is **very important** to keep `]` at first position in bracket expression after `^` and keep `[` at last position.

PS: I have removed `[[:blank:]]*` fromn regex for sake of readability.

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/f0oZbX)

Comment: Thank You. Looks like it is working now. I will test few more scenarios and getback!!

Answer (score 1):

Not quoting the test works for me. Example :

```
pair_format="^([[:blank:]]*\[[[:blank:]]*[^=[\]]+[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[^=[\]]+[[:blank:]]*\][[:blank:]]*)+$"

[[ ! "[X=Y][A=B][C=D][FASLFJSDLF=9]" =~ $pair_format ]] && echo "Match"
```

Output

`Match`

Regards!

Edit

Correcting your script here. This worked perfectly here :

```
CUSTOM_ARGS_KV='[X=Y][A=B][C=D][FASLFJSDLF=9]' 

if [ ! -z "$CUSTOM_ARGS_KV" ]; 
then
    pair_format='^([[:blank:]]*\[[[:blank:]]*[^=[\]]+[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[^=[\]]+[[:blank:]]*\][[:blank:]]*)+$'
    if [[ ! $CUSTOM_ARGS_KV =~ $pair_format ]]
    then
        echo 'Error! CUSTOM_ARGS_KV is not according to format [key1=value1] [key2=value2] etc. Or either of key/value of a pair are kept blank'
    #exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Sorry, its not working for me, when I used the argument $CUSTOM_ARGS_KV in place of hardcoded values in if conditon.

Comment: You DO need to quote the left side parameter. Maybe you did not quote the **$CUSTOM_ARGS_KV**. Its only the regex what you are not supposed to quote

Comment: Have you tried copy pasting the answer in your terminal?

Comment: Yes I tried. I added double quotes "$CUSTOM_ARGS_KV". Can you try from your end. I am not getting result.

Comment: can you show me your Bash version? **bash --version**?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: Got your point. [[ ! "$CUSTOM_ARGS_KV" =~ $pair_format ]] && echo "Match" is working. But, why if is not working... I am not sure..  if [[ ! "$CUSTOM_ARGS_KV" =~ $pair_format ]]; then echo "invalid!!!!"; else echo "valid"; fi

Comment: you have an ever newer version of Bash than I do so this should work. can you edit your question and paste your entire script?  Ill try to fix it.

Comment: Edited my question. Please find the script at the end. I cannot paste entire script as it is 600 lines long, and entire part is not reltated to this context.

Comment: Please try to run my edited version here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php. you will see it works perfectly

Answer (score -2):

I ran your code and get the following error:

```
./testing: line 3: =[X=Y][A=B][C=D][FASLFJSDLF=9]: command not found
./testing: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
./testing: line 5: `if [[ ! "$CUSTOM_ARGS_KV" =~ "$pair_format" ]];    then;             echo "invalid!!!!"; else echo "valid"; fi'
```

The line 3 problem was that I didn't take of the $ from CUSTOM_ARGS_KV.

Use the if like this:

```
if [[ ! "$CUSTOM_ARGS_KV" =~ "$pair_format" ]]
then
....echo "invalid!!!!" 
else 
....echo "valid"
fi
```